# Pass a url stored in model to jquery var (for KendoGrid)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, variables, telerik-mvc

I have an issue which seems ridiculous. I'm trying to set the WebApi base service url from my controller and pass it to the front end / jquery for use in the KendoGrid. I can't seem to pass a URL in a string variable from within a model to my jquery var without getting an error, such as:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:55607/api/StockSelectorWebApi?" + sea...
```

and if I UrlEncode it:

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
var crudServiceBaseUrl = http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a55607%2fapi%2fStockSelectorWeb...
```

my query is as follows:

```
    var crudServiceBaseUrl = @Model.CrudBaseServiceUrl;

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "WedNo",
                fields: {
                    WedNo: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "number" },
                    MillNo: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                    Location: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                    Stockholder: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                    Auths: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and my model:

```
model.CrudBaseServiceUrl = Server.UrlEncode("http://localhost:55607/api/StockSelectorWebApi?searchType=Arrival&parameterOne=" + model.Arrival);
```

EDIT: Oddly enough I also had tried

```
model.CrudBaseServiceUrl = "'URLHERE'";
```

and

```
model.CrudBaseServiceUrl = "'" + "URLHERE" + "'";
```

But neither worked, but as was pointed out below (in the accepted answer) just do:

```
model.CrudBaseServiceUrl = "URLHERE";
```

and then

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = '@Model.CrudBaseServiceUrl';
```

pffttt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var crudServiceBaseUrl = '@Model.CrudBaseServiceUrl'

basically, if you use string variables coming from the server within javascript you should use quotes around them. no need to encode or anything.